# Angularjs write to Azure SQL table

Tags: sql, angularjs, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to create a form using AngularJS and host it on Azure. And when a user fills in the form, the data should be written to a table on Azure SQL server.

I would be most grateful if someone could give me some pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Whats your backend?

Comment: Supposed to be SQL server on azure. It's just that I don't know how to get Angularjs to write to Azure SQL server

Comment: @SharePointDummy, typically, AngularJS would interact with services (e.g. RESTful) and which perform data access. The client would not read/write to the database directly.

Comment: Adding to @DanGuzman , check the `form` in `angularjs` and make the API calls on `ng-submit` of the form using either `$http` or `$resource`. Try to read abt these pointers and update the question if you get stuck somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of step by step examples:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/26/build-crud-app-aspnetcore-angular

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210559/ASP-NET-Core-Angular-Build-from-Scratch-a-We

https://dzone.com/articles/crud-operation-with-angular-5-http-client-and-aspn

https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs.md

http://www.dotnetmob.com/angular-5-tutorial/angular-5-with-web-api-crud-application/

Comment: You my friend are a life saver! I owe you a drink